# How is the correct syntax/call to get the sls-file working - salt

Tags: module, yaml, salt-stack, reactor

I'm trying to build a reactor sls file, which starts running when an event occurs.

The content of the sls file should be as the following cli commands:

```
sudo salt minion git.add /srv/salt .
sudo salt minion git.commit /srv/salt test
sudo salt minion git.push /srv/salt origin master identity=/home/autogit/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If i run the code bellow triggered by the reactor. I get the following error message.

```
[DEBUG   ] Reactor is populating module client cache
[ERROR   ] An un-handled exception from the multiprocessing process 'Reactor-9:1' was caught:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/process.py", line 765, in _run
    return self._original_run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/reactor.py", line 271, in run
    self.call_reactions(chunks)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/reactor.py", line 228, in call_reactions
    self.wrap.run(chunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/reactor.py", line 330, in run
    self.populate_client_cache(low)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/reactor.py", line 324, in populate_client_cache
    self.reaction_class[reaction_type](self.opts['conf_file'])
KeyError: u'module'
[CRITICAL] Engine 'reactor' could not be started!
```

I've tried different syntax (old style and new style) but couldn't figure out what the problem is. Always getting an KeyError: u'module' or u'git'.

Also tried it with runner function to run it locally on the master.

```
git pull:
  module.run:
    - git.pull:
      - cwd: /srv/salt
      - remote: git@git.xyz.com:user/sbt.git
      - identity: /home/autogit/.ssh/id_rsa
    - git.add:
      - cwd: /srv/salt
      - filename: .
    - git.commit:
      - cwd: /srv/salt
      - remote: git@git.xyz.com:user/sbt.git
    - git.push:
      - cwd: /srv/salt
      - remote: git@git.xyz.com:user/sbt.git
      - identity: /home/autogit/.ssh/id_rsa



salt --versions-report
Salt Version:
           Salt: 2019.2.0

Dependency Versions:
           cffi: Not Installed
       cherrypy: unknown
       dateutil: 2.6.1
      docker-py: Not Installed
          gitdb: 2.0.3
      gitpython: 2.1.8
          ioflo: Not Installed
         Jinja2: 2.10
        libgit2: Not Installed
        libnacl: Not Installed
       M2Crypto: Not Installed
           Mako: 1.0.7
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
 msgpack-python: 0.5.6
   mysql-python: Not Installed
      pycparser: Not Installed
       pycrypto: 2.6.1
   pycryptodome: Not Installed
         pygit2: Not Installed
         Python: 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15)
   python-gnupg: 0.4.1
         PyYAML: 3.12
          PyZMQ: 16.0.2
           RAET: Not Installed
          smmap: 2.0.3
        timelib: Not Installed
        Tornado: 4.5.3
            ZMQ: 4.2.5

System Versions:
           dist: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
         locale: UTF-8
        machine: x86_64
        release: 4.15.0-46-generic
         system: Linux
        version: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
```

Since i'm quite new to Salt, hopefully you can give me a hint what i'm doing wrong:

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the master config.

1. About `module.run` confusion: add in your settings (minion and maybe to master since I don't know your use-case)

```
use_superseded:
  - module.run
```

That will enable your syntax, more doc about this here: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.module.html#salt.states.module.run
In general: you are executing *execution modules* from the place that *state modules* are allowed only (the term module is heavily overused in salt...)

2. You didn't provide the full Master config. Reactor requires dedicated config to match events to sls files:
   https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/master.html#master-reactor-settings

You can also check the doc I've written some time ago about events and reactors:
https://github.com/kiemlicz/util/wiki/Salt-Events-and-Reactor

**Assuming** you've configured your events-to-sls-files-matching in master config, your provided sls:

```
git pull:
  module.run:
    - git.pull:
      - cwd: /srv/salt
      - remote: git@git.xyz.com:user/
...
```

will not work.
Mind that reaction happens on **Salt Master** thus the reaction sls file need to provide type of reaction (local, runner etc.) since it's no longer 'view of one minion' but possibly of tons of minions!
First create *runner* reaction type (which delegates to some orchestration sls file which will contain your logic wrapped with (I think) [`salt.function`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.saltmod.html#salt.states.saltmod.function) )

Help yourself with aforementioned github link to my attempt of explaining Reactor.
Refer to official doc as well: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/reactor/index.html